# Unable to Uninstall Anaconda3 on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I can't uninstall Anaconda3 from my system.

I have spent a lot of hours searching for a solution to this and have tried everything I can find and was able to understand.

I have Anaconda3 2023.09-0 installed on Windows 11

[Anaconda in Control Pannel > Programs and Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT94H.png)

I have gone through a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590572/unable-to-uninstall-anaconda) but that only talks about the options I have tried.

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstall from Control Pannel > Programs and Features
2. Uninstall from Settings > Apps > Installed Apps
3. Right Click on "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe" > Run as Administrator

In all the cases I encounter the same error:

**Failed to run pre_uninstall**

[Error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMuRP.jpg)

Even though the image shows Uninstallation complete, the list in Programs and Features till has Anaconda3 and I am still able to run python.

I have also tried the: `> anaconda-clean --yes` which seems to go well but trying to uninstall still gives the same error.

I am basically a software noob so I apologise in advance and appreciate all the help and feedback you can offer.

Comment: install it, then uninstall it